# A solution to $\dot{y}(t)=y(t)^2−y(t)+1$ with initial condition $y(0)=1$ is increasing, decreasing or constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> A solution to $\dot{y}(t)=y(t)^2−y(t)+1$ with initial condition $y(0)=1$ is increasing, decreasing or constant ?

I am in a bit of a dead-end with this question. I've tried solving the equation, but I get this complicated expression (from Wolfram Alpha) that I'm not even sure how to interpret:

$$ y(t)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tan\left[\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(t+c_1)\right]+\frac{1}{2}. $$

Finally, I've also considered using the regular fixed-point method for dynamical systems – setting $\dot{y}(t)=0$ and analysing the qualitative behaviour of the equation. However, the resulting expression $y^2-y+1=0$ does not have real roots, which makes me suspect that this is not the way to approach this, either.

Any ideas on what the question may be asking, or ideas on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: To interpret the wolfram alpha solution, you need to choose $c_1$ such that $y(0) = 1$. Conveniently, the resulting arctangent has a closed-form expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: The RHS has no real roots, which means it is always positive. What does that say about $y'(t)$?

Answer (score 3):

$$\dot{y}(t)=y(t)^2−y(t)+1$$
$$\dot{y}(t)=y(t)^2−y(t)+\dfrac 1  4+\dfrac 34$$
$$\dot{y}(t)=\left(y(t)−\dfrac 1  2\right)^2+\dfrac 34> 0$$